# Print the numbers 1-100 in 10 in Swing

Tags: java, swing

For some reason I can't get my code to work the way I want to. My task is to print the numbers between 1-100 in 10 rows (Swing - not console!), but the numbers are only in one line instead of 10 (i.g. 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 etc) if I take away the string in the last "textLabel.setText(/////);".

I'm not allowed to use HTML-codes in the labels because it hasn't been discussed in class. Is there another method?

What can I do to fix the code/loop?

```
int i; 
if (event.getSource() ==fåFramMönster){
    String gridPattern = ""; 
    for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        gridPattern = gridPattern + " " + Integer.toString(i); 
        textLabel.setText(gridPattern);
        if (i%10==0) {
            textLabel.setText(gridPattern + "\n");
        }
    }
```

I've tried in console and it works fine (I get the right results):

```
for(int k = 1; k <= 100; k++) {
    System.out.print(" " + k);
    if(k % 10 == 0)
        System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because `setText` **replaces** the content, so the newline added by `setText(gridPattern + "\n")` is discarded when the next value is added.

You never insert `\n` in the `gridPattern` value itself.

Code should be:

```
String gridPattern = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    gridPattern = gridPattern + " " + Integer.toString(i); 
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        gridPattern = gridPattern + "\n";
    }
}
textLabel.setText(gridPattern);
```

Better yet, if you've learned about `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    buf.append(' ').append(i);
    if (i % 10 == 0) {
        buf.append('\n');
    }
}
textLabel.setText(buf.toString());
```

As mentioned in many comments, to format the text, it needs to be HTML, so must start with `<html>`, end with `</html>`, and lines must be separated by `"<br>"`.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
buf.append("<html>");
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    buf.append(i).append(i % 10 == 0 ? "<br>" : " ");
}
buf.append("</html>");
textLabel.setText(buf.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to helping me, but it still doesn't show up as 10 rows... maybe I've done something weird somewhere else (wouldn't be the first time xD).

Comment: I don't think `JLabel` honors the '\n' character. That is why we have so many Qs "Why isn't \n working in JLabel?" and As "Use HTML instead". There are some other answers as well besides HTML, which is why I was trying to identify what Cathy can/cannot use in her class.

Comment: @Aaron True. Doesn't make my observations wrong though, just whether to use `\n` or `<br>`. If OP's code is changed to use `<br>`, it still wouldn't work, since the value with the `<br>` is immediately replaced.

Comment: @Andreas I don't disagree. And there are other issues and improvements too, which you've mostly covered by switching to building up a string. Unfortunately we don't know where to point OP without more information, and OP is likely not sure what information is relevant since we don't want a list of every single thing that has been covered. So it's like pulling teeth. Anyway, your main point here is valid, so +1.

Comment: @Andreas I changed it to <br>, and it does indeed print where I would like the new rows to be, but it's not actually a new row now - it simply printed <br> inbetween instead

Comment: @CathyCathola If you are going to go with the HTML way of doing it, then the label needs to know that it is using HTML format. So the text needs to start with "<html>" and end with "</html>", otherwise it will not know to treat the "<br>" as an HTML line break.